# Error changing the settings of a video python opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-3.8

i'm having a problem trying to set the width and height of a video that it's been played.
I don't know if the commands to change the settings are in the right place really. The code is the next one:

```
if (vid.isOpened()== False):
    print("El archivo de mierda no se pudo abrir")

while (vid.isOpened()):
    cv2.VideoCapture.set(3, 900)
    cv2.VideoCapture.set(4, 900)
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

    else:
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the error that comes up is the next one:

TypeError: descriptor 'set' for 'cv2.VideoCapture' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set is a member function of the VideoCapture object. 
So you need to call set function on the VideoCapture object as shown below

```
vid.set(3, 900)
vid.set(4, 900)
```

Instead of

```
cv2.VideoCapture.set(3, 900)
cv2.VideoCapture.set(4, 900)
```